# Is a booster vaccine required to travel between cities in France by bus?

Tags: paperwork, france, covid-19, buses, vaccinations

I live in Toulouse. I haven't received a COVID-19 booster vaccine yet and I am planning to take a bus to Bordeaux, which is 2-3 hours away. I am not sure if anyone will be checking my vaccine passport. I do know that vaccine passes are no longer required in France.

Will I need a COVID-19 booster shot and/or a vaccine passport to make this trip?

Comment: @RobertColumbia, please keep the feel of the question when you edit it, even when language does ask for quite a lot of changes. I would say that about half of what you have edited here would have been enough and would have kept the feel of the original text much better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since March 14th, vaccination certificates ("Pass vaccinal") are [no longer required](https://www.gouvernement.fr/info-coronavirus/pass-sanitaire) for long-distance travel within France, be it by bus, train, or air. The "Pass sanitaire" (proof of either vaccination or a recent negative test or recovery) is still required in health-related establishments.

Masks are still required on board trains, buses and aircraft, as well as in stations (though information on this topic is not very consistent).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am relieved now. I will write down my experience after tomorrow. My trip is tomorrow and I hope everything will be alright ^^.
Merci beaucoup